# Can I create a match against a generic type that implements Pattern?

Tags: generics, pattern-matching, rust

I think this might work if I can work out the lifetime notation, am I wrong?

```
pub fn from<T:Pattern>(from: T) -> Result<Tag, &'static str> {
    match from {
        'A'|"A" => Ok(Tag::ChA),
        'B'|"B" => Ok(Tag::ChB),
        'C'|"C" => Ok(Tag::ChC),
        'D'|"D" => Ok(Tag::ChD),
        'T'|"Tmpr" => Ok(Tag::Tmpr),
        'Y'|"Batt" => Ok(Tag::Batt),
        'L'|"Acc" => Ok(Tag::Acc),
        _ => Err("Error: unknown channel"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Matching only works with concrete types, so the answer is no. Nothing is known about the type `T` here except that we can call the methods defined in `Pattern` on it (which are for searching in a string).

Answer (score -1):

No sure if this is what you're looking for, but a handy work-around I found is:

```
let value: T = Default::default();
        match value.type_id() {

            'A'|"A" => Ok(Tag::ChA),
            'B'|"B" => Ok(Tag::ChB),
            'C'|"C" => Ok(Tag::ChC),
            'D'|"D" => Ok(Tag::ChD),
            'T'|"Tmpr" => Ok(Tag::Tmpr),
            'Y'|"Batt" => Ok(Tag::Batt),
            'L'|"Acc" => Ok(Tag::Acc),
            _ => Err("Error: unknown channel"),
        };
```

Note that T has to implement Default

Comment: that doesn't work because the value is already defined elsewhere. I have a concrete instance that I pass into the generic function. Also what is the `list` variable?